How to find the functions that communicate with a using a dissasembler
Im starting to learn dissasembly and im willing to know how to look for specific functions.
Im aiming to find functions that communicate with the server specifically the ones that send data.
I have no idea how to do so, i have tried to naviguate through Relyze and my debugger without any success.
Is there any process or step i must followed in order to find what im looking for ?
I also have trouble finding good ressources about reverse engeenering, if you can tell me some i would be glad.
PS : The client im trying to debug is using Adobe Air maybe its important.
